# TypeScript - type guard for parameter property

Tags: typescript

Let's say I have a function such as

```
export function is<T extends string>(
  element: ModdleElement,
  type: T
): element is BpmnElement<T>;
```

Let's add an overload

```
export function is<T extends string>(
  element: Base,
  type: T
): boolean;
```

The `Base` interface is

```
interface Base {
   businessObject: ModdleElement;
}
```

---

I'd like to apply the type guard also for the overload, to the `businessObject` field, so that

```
if (is(base, '...')) {
   const t = base.businessObject.myProp; // Correctly cast
}
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Type guards usually work by narrowing unions. In this case `Base` is not a union, but we ca still get things to work using an intersection with something that has a property of the specified sub-type in the `is` return type .

```
class ModdleElement { p: any; } // placeholder
class BpmnElement<T> extends ModdleElement { myProp: T } // placeholder

export declare function is<T extends string>(
    element: ModdleElement,
    type: T
): element is BpmnElement<T>;
export declare function is<T extends string>(
    element: Base,
    type: T
): element is (Base & { businessObject: BpmnElement<T> });


interface Base {
    businessObject: ModdleElement;
}
declare let base: Base;

if (is(base, '...')) {
    const t = base.businessObject.myProp; // Correctly cast
}
```

Comment: That's awesome! Thanks. The previous version used `Omit`, why did you prefer the intersection one?

Comment: @LppEdd yeah it did, I realized intersecting with a property of the derived type will produce the same result with less code :)